# Accessing the tail of a fusion::cons

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

How do I officially access the tail of a `boost::fusion::cons` object? I know I can do it easily by accessing the `cdr` data member of the `cons` structure, but the documentation of Boost 1.54.0 doesn't specify that there is such a member, so I guess I'm not supposed to do that. `at_c<1>(cons)` will give me only the head of the tail, but what I need is the whole tail structure, an object of the same type as the `Cdr` template parameter of my `cons`.

I'm sorry if I'm missing something completely obvious.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be completely obvious... I'm using `std::pair` now instead, since I don't really need the list view. Still I'm a bit surprised that there's no obvious way to get at the tail of a `cons`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this list implementation

https://github.com/niitsuma/scm2cpp.hpp/blob/master/scm2cpp.hpp

In this implementation

```
cons => std::pair

car(fusion::list) => fusion::car  

cons(value , fusion::list) => fusion::list
```

...

and so on